# how to bind image-url in angular 2 and show in bootstrap cards

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a bootstrap class

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="imageUrl">Image Url</label>
  <input #imageUrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.imageUrl" 
  name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control" required 
  url>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && 
  imageUrl.invalid">
  <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">Image Url is required</div>
  <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url">Please enter valid URL</div> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

I want to bind this class imageurl and show in bootstrap cards, i write following code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" 
  [src]="product.imageUrl"*ngIf="product.imageUrl">
  </div>
 </div>
```

when i give a url in my input field it failed to bind property & blank card is shown..

Comment: Whats the value of product.imageUrl ? and whats the error?

Comment: I guess your code is all fine. Just make sure you give the image url with proper image extension. If you are using google links then make sure it has a proper image extension like .jpg or other image formats.

Comment: in console there is no error but broken image is shown in cards....